# I am reading the code for Redis. I have some doubts and would like to ask for advice

Tags: redis, zset

These are the codes of zset, when cleanup，the value of added and update will be 0, can `if (added || updated)` will be true？

`cleanup: // 释放申请的内存 zfree(scores); if (added || updated) { // 标记修改的键 signalModifiedKey(c,c->db,key); // 发送事件通知 notifyKeyspaceEvent(NOTIFY_ZSET, incr ? "zincr" : "zadd", key, c->db->id); } }`

Comment: Please click [edit] and try to improve your question. It is hard to understand and there is no context. Thank you.